# Change jHipster login authentication page

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I wish to give login page to authenticate the user and then redirect it to **jHipster** created Home page. 
The login page is the first thing the user should see

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.0.0",
    "baseName": "vconnect",
    "packageName": "com.zenfact.vconnect",
    "packageFolder": "com/zenfact/vconnect",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "559bbe3167552d040ba24d16506d389a7ba851c3",
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "zh-cn",
      "fr",
      "hi",
      "ja"
    ]
  }
}
```

**this is what i did in index.html**

```
 <div ui-view="navbar"  ng-cloak></div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="well" ui-view="content">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" ng-controller="LoginController as vm" ng-hide="vm.isAuthenticated()" data-ng-init="translate()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <h1 translate="login.title">Sign in</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="vm.authenticationError" translate="login.messages.error.authentication">
                <strong>Failed to sign in!</strong> Please check your credentials and try again.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <form class="form" role="form" ng-submit="vm.login($event)">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" translate="global.form.username">username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="userName" ng-model="vm.username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" translate="login.form.password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password"
                           ng-model="vm.password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rememberMe">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" ng-model="vm.rememberMe" checked>
                        <span translate="login.form.rememberme">Remember me</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" translate="login.form.button">Sign in</button>
            </form>
            <p></p>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <a class="alert-link" href="" ng-click="vm.requestResetPassword()" translate="login.password.forgot">Did you forget your password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-warning" translate="global.messages.info.register" translate-compile>
                You don't have an account yet? <a class="alert-link" href="" ng-click="vm.register()">Register a new account</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wish to have login page as default page, authenticate the user there and then redirect user according to result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit home state in home.state.js to require authentication

```
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
```

Comment: as of now jhipster provide a index.html as default page, i wish to have a login page as default page which authenticates any user and then redirects the user to index page. when i inserted the login code in index.html it was not translating

Comment: I have added the changes done in index.html in question above

Comment: Have you tried what I proposed before modifying index.html? It is supposed to do what you want with minimal changes. If you go to home page without being authenticated you're redirected to login. If you don't understand how authorities (permissions) work you're going to either add complexity or create security issues

Comment: what you have suggested works for me but my project manage is not satisfied with login dialog pop-up instead he wants a login page which on successful login redirects to home page.

Comment: If there is really no way around it then I will convince him but If there is a way to do that without sacrificing security please let me know.

Comment: Too long to describe here, your manager will certainly let you spend more time to get this working then.