# Changing Jhipster/Angular landing page from home.html to login.html

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

There is a modal login.html in jhipster generated project. As landing page, home.html comes up first as default. Is there any configuration point to change the landing page? How can I set login.html as landing page?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042983/change-jhipster-login-authentication-page

Answer (score 1):

Change code in home.state.js as authorities and url so u can redirect to login.html

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
                parent: 'app',
                url: '/home',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm'
                    }
                }
            }
```